# Oracle's to_number - What's wrong?

Tags: sql, oracle

What is wrong with the below format specifier for to_number?

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER('0,22', '0,99') * 100 FROM DUAL;
```

The result is 2200 instead of 22 -- what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try:

```
TO_NUMBER('0,22', '9D99')
```

Unlike a literal comma, the `D` will only match the decimal separator.  So if this fails, your decimal separator is probably a `.`, not a `,`.

You can use this command to see the decimal separator and the thousand separator:

```
select value from nls_session_parameters
where parameter = 'NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS'
```

If this returns `.,`, the comma is your thousand separator.

To change the separator for a single query, you could:

```
select TO_NUMBER('0,22','9D99','nls_numeric_characters=,.') from dual;
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick guess:
0.22 versus 0,22 (same for 9.99 versus 0,99 )

?